# Estimating Trigonometric Function with Taylor Polynomial

Tags: taylor-expansion

Suppose we wrote a fourth degree Taylor polynomial for $f(x) = \sin x$ at a center of $a = \frac{\pi}{6}$ as 
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \Big(x - \frac{\pi}{6}\Big) - \frac{1}{4} \Big(x - \frac{\pi}{6}\Big)^2 - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{12} \Big(x - \frac{\pi}{6}\Big)^3 + \frac{1}{48} \Big(x - \frac{\pi}{6}\Big)^4
\end{align*}
Using Taylor's Inequality over the interval $0 \leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{3}$, we estimate an accuracy of $\lvert R_4 (x) \rvert = 0.0003$.

Now, however, suppose we wanted to -- per the instructions, this should be possible, though I can't quite grasp it -- use this polynomial to estimate $\sin (38^{\circ}) = \sin \Big(\frac{19 \pi}{90}\Big)$ accurate to five decimal places. Is there some kind of algebraic manipulation of this polynomial we can perform, or is it only possible if we add terms?

Thanks.

Comment: You can simply substitute $x = \sin \frac{19\pi}{90}$ into the approximation you have. As the Taylor series approximates the curve, the points are also approximated as well.

Comment: How would I know if it were accurate enough, though? It seems that the accuracy is only 0.0003, though I need an accuracy within 0.00001.

Comment: I just realised that [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1051330) covers the same problem as your one. You can go take a look at it.

Comment: Oh, my apologies. I wish I had seen it earlier. I'll delete this one. Thanks for linking this.

Comment: Actually, now that I read it, it seems that was the step prior to the one I'm stuck on. (The answer to his question, I believe, is 0.0003.) I'm somewhat confused on how to proceed, using this to estimate a trigonometric function but to an even higher accuracy than the one computed with the Taylor Inequality.